# I am getting the "Sequence contains no elements error" while running a build pipeline in Azure DevOps services to deploy a cloud service (classic)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I have created an Azure Classic type service connection. Is there anything I am missing?

I am then using this Azure Classic Service connection to deploy the cloud service to Azure.

```
Azure Deployment: D:\a\1\a\*.cspkg

View raw log

Starting: Azure Deployment: D:\a\1\a\*.cspkg
----------------------------------------------------------------
Task         : Azure Cloud Service deployment
Description  : Deploy an Azure Cloud Service
Version      : 1.175.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cloud-powershell-deployment
----------------------------------------------------------------
Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\azure_2.1.0\Azure\2.1.0\Azure.psd1 -Global

Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\azurerm_2.1.0\AzureRM\2.1.0\AzureRM.psd1 -Global

##[warning]The names of some imported commands from the module 'AzureRM.Websites' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the 

Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.

Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\azurerm_2.1.0\AzureRM.Profile\2.1.0\AzureRM.Profile.psm1 -Global

Add-AzureAccount -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential

##[error]Sequence contains no elements
-
##[error]There was an error with the Azure credentials used for the deployment.
-
Finishing: Azure Deployment: D:\a\1\a\*.cspkg
```

PS: I am using the classic editor to create the pipelines and not YAML builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ##[error]There was an error with the Azure credentials used for the deployment.

You could change to use the `Certificate Based` as the verification method.

[image]

To use the `Certificate Based` method, you could use the following script to create the .cer file.

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName yourdomain.cloudapp.net -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -KeyLength 2048 -KeySpec "KeyExchange"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "your-password" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath ".\my-cert-file.pfx" -Password $password
Export-Certificate -Type CERT -Cert $cert -FilePath .\my-cert-file.cer
```

Then you could get the [upload certificate with the management portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-certs-create#powershell).

At the same time , you could get the Public key with .cer file.

[image]

This key is used in the service connection.

You can refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304839/azure-deployment-task-fails-on-powershell-credential-setting) to get the possible cause of the problem

Comment: This method worked. Thanks Kevin !!
I am still trying to figure out why this wouldn't work the Credentials.